# automatic data reload after database update

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I have the following problem. In the file +page.svelte I have a list of all items that should be bought.
the check button triggers a function that writes a true to the database. This marks the item as purchased. This activates a styling that passes through the text.
Unfortunately, this causes the page to reload. However, when the page is reloaded, the data from the database is not retrieved. You can find the code I use to land the list and update it in the file +page.servre.ts
How can I prevent the list from being displayed after a check? I don't want to have to reload the list every time I buy something. Would it be possible to have the data displayed updated?
the code is based on ts and svelte.kit

+page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { enhance } from "$app/forms";

  export let data;

  let startDate;
  let endDate;

  console.log('data', data.ingredients);
</script>

<h1>Einkaufsliste Abfragen</h1>
<form action="?/shoppingList" use:enhance method="POST">
  <p>Startdatum: <input type="date" name="startet" bind:value={startDate} /></p>
  <p>Enddatum: <input type="date" name="ending" bind:value={endDate} /></p>
  <button>Generieren</button>
</form>

<h2>Einkauflste von {startDate} bis {endDate}</h2>

{#each data.ingredients as ingred}
<form action="?/ingredCheck" use:enhance method="POST">
  <div class:checked={ingred.checked === true}>
    <button disabled={ingred.checked === true}>check</button>
      {ingred.amount}
      {ingred.unit}
      {ingred.name}
    <input type="hidden" name="startTime" bind:value={startDate} />
    <input type="hidden" name="endTime" bind:value={endDate} />
    <input type="hidden" name="unit-id" value={ingred.unit} />
    <input type="hidden" name="ingredient" value={ingred.name} />
  </div>
</form>  
{/each}

<form
  action="?/cleanShoppingList"
  use:enhance
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <input type="hidden" name="startTime" bind:value={startDate} />
  <input type="hidden" name="endTime" bind:value={endDate} />
  <button>Markierte Entfernen</button>
</form>

<style>
  .checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
</style>
```

+page.server.ts

```
let start:string;
let end:string;


export const load = async ({ locals }) => {
  const { supabase } = locals;
  
  if (start && end) {
    const { data: planRecipeData, error: planRecipeError } = await supabase
    .from('shopping-list')
    .select(`
      id,
      date,
      ingredients (
        id,
        name
      ),
      units (
        id,
        name
      ),
      amount,
      checked
    `)
    .lte('date', end)
    .gte('date', start); 
  
    if (planRecipeError) {
      console.log('Error fetching data', planRecipeError);
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data from the database.');
    }
    
    start = ''
    end = ''

    let ingredients = planRecipeData.reduce((acc, ingredient) => {
      const id = ingredient.ingredients.name + ingredient.units.name;
      const accIndex = acc.findIndex(i => i.id === id)
      if (accIndex > -1) {
        acc[accIndex].amount += ingredient.amount;
      } else {
        acc.push({
          id,
          name: ingredient.ingredients.name,
          unit: ingredient.units.name,
          amount: ingredient.amount,
          checked: ingredient.checked,
        })
      }
      return acc
    }, [] as { id: string, name: string, unit: string, amount: number}[]);
  
    return {
      planRecipes: planRecipeData,
      ingredients,
    };
  }
  return {
    planRecipes: [],
    ingredients: [],
  };
};

async function reloadShoppingList(supabase, start, end) {
  console.log('load data')
  console.log('start date', start);
  console.log('end date', end);
  const { data: reloadShoppingData, error: reloadShoppingError } = await supabase
    .from('shopping-list')
    .select(`
    id,
    date,
    ingredients (
      id,
      name
    ),
    units (
      id,
      name
    ),
    amount,
    checked
  `)
    .lte('date', end)
    .gte('date', start);

  if (reloadShoppingError) {
    console.log('Error fetching data', reloadShoppingError);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data from the database.');
  }

  const ingredients = reloadShoppingData.reduce((acc, ingredient) => {
    const id = ingredient.ingredients.name + ingredient.units.name;
    const accIndex = acc.findIndex(i => i.id === id)
    if (accIndex > -1) {
      acc[accIndex].amount += ingredient.amount;
    } else {
      acc.push({
        id,
        name: ingredient.ingredients.name,
        unit: ingredient.units.name,
        amount: ingredient.amount,
        checked: ingredient.checked,
      })
    }
    return acc
  }, [] as { id: string, name: string, unit: string, amount: number, checked: boolean }[]);

  console.log('end from reload', ingredients, reloadShoppingData)
  let data = reloadShoppingData;
  return {
    reloadShoppings: reloadShoppingData,
    ingredients,
    success:true
  };
}


export const actions = {
  shoppingList: async ({ request, locals }) => {
    const { supabase } = locals;
    const data = await request.formData();

    start = data.get('startet') as string;
    end = data.get('ending') as string;

    return {success:true};
  },

  cleanShoppingList: async ({request, locals}) => {
    const { supabase } = locals;
    const data = await request.formData();

    const ingredName = data.getAll('ingredient');
  },

  ingredCheck: async ({request, locals}) => {
    const {supabase} = locals;
    let data = await request.formData();
    const unitId = data.get('unit-id');
    const ingredient = data.get('ingredient');
    const start = data.get('startTime');
    const end = data.get('endTime');
   
    const { data: ingredCheckData, error: ingredCheckError } = await supabase
    .from('shopping-list')
    .select(`
      id,
      date,
      ingredients (
        id,
        name
      ),
      units (
        id,
        name
      ),
      amount,
      checked
    `)

    if (ingredCheckError) {
      console.log('Error', ingredCheckError)
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data from the database.');
    }


    
    const uncheckedIds = ingredCheckData.map(entry => entry.id);

    let updateChecked = [];

    uncheckedIds.forEach((value) => {
      const matchingEntry = ingredCheckData.find(entry => entry.id === value && entry.ingredients.name === ingredient && entry.units.name === unitId);
    
      if (matchingEntry) {
        updateChecked.push({
          id: value,
          checked: true
        });
      }
    });

    if (uncheckedIds.length > 0) {
      const { data: updateData, error: updateError } = await supabase
        .from('shopping-list')
        .upsert(updateChecked)
        .in('id', uncheckedIds)
        .eq('ingredients.name', ingredient)
        .eq('units.name', unitId)
        .select(`
          id,
          date,
          ingredients (
            id,
            name
          ),
          units (
            id,
            name
          ),
          amount,
          checked
        `);
    
      if (updateError) {
        console.error('Failed to update checked status:', updateError.message);
        throw new Error('Failed to update checked status in the database.');
      }
    
      console.log('Checked status updated successfully:', updateData);

      
    } else {
      console.log('No entries to update.');
    }
    
    // Lade die Einkaufsliste neu
    data = await reloadShoppingList(supabase, start, end);
    // data = {...data, ...updatedData};
    return {
      ingredCheckData: data,
    };
  },
}
```